# Can I do a pruned fast sync?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, state-trie-pruning

I would like to do a fast bootstrap of the Ethereum blockchain with minimal disk space usage. Can `geth` do a pruned fast sync?

Comment: Actually, only Geth can do a fast sync, and yes, it results in a pruned database :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `geth --fast`:

```
--fast              Enable fast syncing through state downloads
```

This only downloads the blockchain and verifies the proof-of-work. It does not commit all transactions included in the blocks and therefore can be considered a *pruned sync* since not the whole state is recalculated.

After the blockchain was downloaded, the client requests the latest state-trie from other nodes and saves it. This is additional data, but this way you can synchronize faster and reduce the disk space requirements by around 80%.